# Themes look all messed up

Tags: 13.04, themes

I am trying to apply themes using the gnome tweak tool.

When I apply my theme in "Current Theme" and "Gtk+ Theme" it goes all weird, it almost never looks ANYTHING like the picture.

I am trying to apply an all black theme with a white icon set and the top bar is white, the background for drop down menus is black with black text etc etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Often times it doesn't apply correctly after setting a theme. To fix that, you should try logging out and logging back in to see if the theme applied correctly.